# How to make asterisk call file as user account or extension

Tags: linux, asterisk, sip

I am trying to figure out why the callerid works when I call with twinkle through asterisk but not when making a call file. The callerid with the call file is always unknown. Twinkle account is setup with user pete. So I want to make asterisk use pete account instead of going directly to freecall. I am using asterisk 13 on ubuntu 18.04. Thank you.

Here is sip.conf

```
[pete]
type=friend
callerid="pete" 
username=pete
secret=12345
;regcontext=pete-internal
regexten=1005
dtmfmode=rfc2833
insecure=invite,port
canreinvite=yes
;nat=yes
qualify=yes
pickupgroup=1
callgroup=1
;mailbox=1000@default
host=dynamic

[freecall]
fromdomain=sip.freecall.com
fromuser=pete
host=sip.freecall.com
insecure=invite,port
defaultuser=pete
secret=********
type=friend
context=public
;qualify=yes
disallow=all
allow=ulaw,alaw,gsm,g726
;nat=yes
;realm=sip.freecall.com
```

Here is extensions.conf

```
exten => _9.,1,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN:1}@freecall)
```

Here is call file

`Channel: SIP/freecall/18004444444
Application: Playback
Data: silence/2&hello-world&silence/1`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a value to `Callerid` in the call file.

Example:

```
Channel: SIP/freecall/18004444444
Callerid: Pete <+14155551212>
Application: Playback
Data: silence/2&hello-world&silence/1
```

More details at https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+Call+Files.